# NetSuite User Event or Workflow on Work Order Close

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I looked all over and I can't see to find how to connect a script to the "close" event of the Work Order. Basically, I need to send an email to the Sales Rep for the order that is being fulfilled when the Work Order is "closed" what approach would be better? A workflow or a UserEvent, I looked at workflow as the Close button is a non-standard event. When I went to set up the workflow I didn't see Work Order as a record to attach it to. Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came to find out is that the Work Order Close status is from a Work Order Close form, in that case just the after submit event takes care of this. Thanks for all your help and sorry I took so long to post this answer

Comment: When you click the 'close' button on a work order the userEvent functions does not get triggered, how did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I'm sure if you did an AfterSubmit User Event, you could get the status of the Work Order.  If WorkOrder == 'closed' (whatever the right status is), run your code.

Alternatively, you could build a saved search of WorkOrders that are closed.  Run a scheduled script every 15 minutes that will send out an email.  Upon sending out the email, tick a checkbox on the WorkOrder to remove it from your Saved Search.

Comment: Great thanks for that, it gives me some place to start, I will let you know, but both good ideas, thanks

Comment: I was looking at the scheduled saved search and it doesn't give schedules shorter than a day, this would need to be almost immediate, 15 minutes would have been fine

Comment: I found out that the Work Order Close button actually goes to another form that I can handle like a normal record submit event, it is listed in the events as Work Order Close as opposed to just Work Order. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

JK, you should be able to build a saved search and use the Alerts feature under the Email tab.  Check the box to "Send email alerts when records are created/updated" and enter the recipients in the list under that.  If you want it to go only to the Sales Rep for that specific customer, as I assume you do, use the list under 'Recipients from Results' sublist. This means you can have the sales rep returned in the search and choose that field, then the alert will be sent to the relevant rep for each record.  You may have to tick the 'Send on Update' option as these records returned by the search will be existing records.

In case you're not familiar with the saved search alerts functionality, the way this works is that as soon as a record of the record type that the saved search is based on meets the conditions specified in the saved search criteria, it fires the alert and emails to the list of recipients specified under 'Specific Recipients' and the result returned by the field specified under 'Recipients from Results.'

Comment: thanks, great answer, although I just got off a call with the client and they need a rather robust set of data points in the email, I will see if I can get all that done this way. thanks again